# Как определяются мониторы в Ubuntu Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, x11

Не приходит понимания того как определяются мониторы в системе...

1. Подключено два монитора (1 - FullHD, 2 - 4k) при вызове команды

`xdpyinfo | grep -B 2 resolution`

пишет следующее:

```
screen #0:
dimensions:    5760x2160 pixels (1524x572 millimeters)
resolution:    96x96 dots per inch
```

Почему screen только один? (Возможно я не понимаю понятия самого screen)

2. На опыте понял, что нельзя установить различный масштаб на разных монторах (например на 1 масштаб 100, на втором 200), неужели это так и масштаб для двух мониторов может быть только один?
3. Из первого вопроса, какие способы есть разделить два монитора на два отдельных Screen'а (конечно же если такое возможно)?

Comment: screen — это как бы типа большой холст, на котором рисуется картинка, а подключенные мониторы показывают отдельные кусочки этого холста. Если картинки мониторов не пересекаются, то это аналог расширения рабочего стола, а если полностью накладываются друг на друга, то это аналог дублирования экранов. А ещё они могут частично накладываться (и как при этом должны вести себя настроки DPI, не знаю...) https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPSKc.png

Comment: Вообще по идее можно добавить несколько независимых screen'ов, но я сейчас попробовал сделать себе dummy device и у меня всё заглючило и вдобавок оконный менеджер крашнулся, возможно проприетарный драйвер nvidia не очень с этим дружит, или в принципе все программы забывают учитывать возможность существования нескольких screen'ов...

Comment: А ещё у мониторов есть panning: когда размер screen'а больше размера монитора (`xrandr --fb ШxВ`), то монитор может двигаться по screen'у вслед за курсором мыши)